# Xamarin.Forms.Webview Crossplatform Geolocation, is it possible?

Tags: visual-studio, webview, geolocation, cross-platform, xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin-forms-webview which refers to a webapp that uses geolocation.
I know that in Android I need to override the method 'OnGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt' as suggested [here](https://gist.github.com/Cheesebaron/ad84740c9bffa7e255c8).

But I don't want to make the implementation for each platform.
How can I enable the location in the xamarin webview?

I'm currently using [this plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin) to get de latitude and longitude.

Thanks.